# Cannot reset password due to does not match any of last n passwords requirement

Tags: macos, password, login

I've recently added some rules using pwpolicy. When I restarted the mac, it asked to reset the password after I input the current password. But I can't satisfy the does not match any of last 3 passwords requirement.

The mac used to have no password policies, so I think it is probably failing because it has no history of old passwords.

Anyone know of a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Apple Support. I was able to reset my password using macOS Utilities in Recovery Mode.

Boot up holding command+R until the macOS Utilities screen comes up and go to Utilities > Terminal. Type in `resetpassword` and follow the prompts. I chose the second option, something like '*my password does not log me in*' which lets you reset your password if you know the current one. It worked in that reset password function but not the one from the login screen.